# Php Exec Wget not working

Tags: php

I need to run some of the **website url**(http://domain.com/user.php?id=uniquetoken) in background by php (note : **The website url** contains html,php and javascript ajax requests)

I tried the below code , but it is not working.Can anyone say what is wrong with this , or any alternative solution.

```
exec("wget http://domain.com/user.php?id=uniquetoken > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

P.s : What i actually need is, when user visits a site, some background process has to be done even after they close the browser.(beacause that backgroud process takes more than 2 minutes to complete)

Comment: Define "not working". What *does* it do?

Comment: It does nothing.. the page keeps loading

Comment: There is a million things that could be going wrong here. Start debugging by looking at what error you are getting from exec() by echoing the return variable. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Are you doing this to get user information from database ?

Comment: To continue a php script after abort, you can use the `ignore_user_abort` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's not the best way doing it. I haven't tried, but when the PHP process terminates, it also kills the child you started with *exec()*. When the user cancels the page load, it will stopped anyway.

You should set up a background process (say, a PHP-CLI script), and set up a mechanism, for triggering that process from the website requests. Say, the bg proc should check for new records in a db table, and if there's any, performs the job, then removes the record. The webpage PHP should insert new job instruction records to it.

Answer (score -2):

Try `file_get_contents("http://domain.com/user.php?id=uniquetoken");`.

PHP has something called 'fopen url wrappers' which allow all filesystem functions to use things like HTTP and FTP, too.

Comment: Please see my question.I need to run the process in background,even after they close the window.

Comment: How does the user closing their browser window affect what happens on the server? If the request has already been sent, the server does not even know that the user closed their browser..

Maybe it would help if you would give us some additional info about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @skrebbel as soon as the server tries to write something back to the client and the browser is gone, it knows the client has disconnecting, thus killing the php process. -1